# How did Neil save the Protagonist at the Opera? Was the inverted bullet there already if we see it from the Protagonist's perspective?

Tags: plot-explanation, tenet

I recently watched *Tenet*. And I have lots of questions and one of them is that.

If we see from the Protagonist's perspective, he was going to disarm/collect the bomb at staircase in the opera house, and is stopped by some armed man. Then we see a hole in the wall/seat getting filled up by concrete remains, and then we see Neil firing a shot.

I understand that it was inverted Neil who actually fired a shot (if seen from his perspective) but when we see it from the viewer/Protagonist's perspective, we see bullet going in the gun that Neil is holding.
So strictly from the viewer's/Protagonist's perspective, who put the bullet in the wall/hole at the first place. Imagine if I was one of the persons sitting there at the opera, I must have not seen any hole at the wall because it was not there before shooting started, then at the time Neil fired that shot, that bullet hole must be there for it to work. So how did it work from the viewer/Protagonist's perspective?

Sorry if I sound confusing and for my bad English as it's not my first language.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that for Tenet, you need to watch it three times, at least once with the subtitles ON (even as an English native;)

Comment: I saw it the week after it was released at my local IMAX (I live in the UK), returning for a second viewing 48 hours later, buying a standard ticket for a normal digital screening in 2.21.1, as despite the highly impressive and enjoyable experience on the first watch the already highly involved film was only just possible to keep up with due to the dialogue having been blown out somewhat by the bombastic IMAX mix, being somewhat clearer and more easy to follow on the second viewing. Although I cannot wait to rewatch the film,the 1080p standard BD has been sitting on my shelf since my copy...

Comment: ...was delivered last Monday and with little else lined up I intend to use it as my cinematic highlight for Christmas Day, so with it being safe to assume I will rewatch it again boxing day morning I cannot wait to unpick it to the degree that I can hopefully start contributing to both your and others questions about the film, possibly accompanied by some queries of my own. With my cinema visits the only positive thing I have done this summer and with the films home release providing the highlight to my Christmas, I will be considering Tenet as perhaps the one good thing to come from 2020

Comment: There has been some discussion about Buller holes, and the General consensus is that our direction of time is the predominant one, so inverted effects gradually sort of wear out over “inverted” time (listen for the phrase “pissing into the wind”  in the movie).  So from our forward perspective, some time before the shootings, a hole slowly begins forming by itself, getting worse over time until the shot is fired (so instantly healing it as shown in the movie). Offhand I think there was a scene (at the airport) where the protagonist watches some Buller holes getting slightly worse.

Comment: See also https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110873/how-long-were-the-bullet-holes-present-in-the-glass-from-the-non-inverted-perspe?r=SearchResults .  Enjoy your Christmas movie watching :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How long were the bullet holes present in the glass from the non-inverted perspective?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/110873/how-long-were-the-bullet-holes-present-in-the-glass-from-the-non-inverted-perspe)